# Bug in MFMailComposeViewController when an iCloud account is present?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, icloud

I have been using MFMailComposeViewController to allow users to send mail from my app without issue. But I have found that if I have an "iCloud account" set up on the device [MFMailComposeViewController [canSendMail]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMailComposeViewController/canSendMail) returns 0.

If I remove the iCloud account, MFMailComposeViewController resumes working.
I have tried; setting the default mail account in iOS settings to my gmail account, setting up my iCloud account with an '@iCloud' email (which I know works because I can send mail from the mail app using it).

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

EDIT

1. I have found that other apps do not have the same problem.
2. While building the content for the email I had been using many threads to fetch data from UIDocument instances concurrently, I have found that if I load the documents sequentially the issue does not occur.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a severe bug to me. You should definitely file a Radar.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a known bug AFAIK ... sounds really strange too,
does it work from inside other apps? (excluding mail)

if not I'd file a bug

Comment: Thanks Daij-Djan, great idea. I found that other apps did not have the same issue sending mail with the iCloud account on, so I have not filed a Radar.

Comment: can you use it even though it returns NO? maybe the other apps dont check